# Centrar avatar en una card

Tags: html, css, angular

Tengo una card que tengo que colocar el avatar en el centro pero en medio de la tarjeta (foto 1), pero no logro centrar el avatar y me queda en el lado izquierdo(foto 2).

Foto 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Foto 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El html lo tengo dentro de una tarjeta mat-card.

```
    <div fxLayout="column">
    <mat-toolbar>Clientes Potenciales</mat-toolbar>
    <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
        <mat-card *ngFor="let current of clients" fxFlex="20">
            <div  mat-card-avatar fxLayoutAlign="center">
                <img mat-card-image src="{{current.avatar}}" class="circulo">
            </div>
            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
                <div class="icon" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                    <span>{{current.companyName}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="person">
                    <span>{{current.trackManager.fullName}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <mat-card-content fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
                <span>Registrado: </span>
                <span>{{current.createdAt | date :'dd/MM/YY'}}</span>
            </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
     .circulo{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
}
```

Comment: despues de top: -35px; agregale un **margin-left:50%; ** puede funcionar

Comment: el problema de agregar el margin es que luego si hago mas pequeña la pantalla la posición no queda en el centro

Answer (score 3):

Hay muchas formas de resolver eso. Una seria usando displey:flex en el contenedor (mat-card) y luego darle un margin:auto el item (el circulo).

```css
.mat-card{
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(54, 92, 205);
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
}

.circulo{
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    background: rgb(138, 138, 138);
    width:  80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mat-card">
           <div class="circulo"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Porfa dale Manito arriba! Así me sube la reputación y puedo seguir ayudando al resto, ya que al ser nuevo por acá, me limitan con las respuestas que puedo dar!